# QGIS 2.4.0 Mac Yosemite compatibility

Tags: qgis, mac, qgis-2.4

I just upgraded to the Beta 2 version of MacOS 10.10 ("Yosemite").  I'm getting an error when I try to "drag and drop" shape files into QGIS.  I'm running QGIS 2.4.0, GDAL 1.11, and MATPLOTLIB 1.3.1.

I can manually add shape files using "Layer --> Add vector layer ..."  So, there is a solid work-around.

It's just the GUI that's not working.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug. You can report this [here](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Bugreports) but you will have to register/login.

Comment: I've got a problem too. When i run gdal xyz; Qgis crash and i can't convert my data. It says that the algorithm can't create the way expected. And this arrived since i upgraded to Yosemite....